# Sorting a dynamically allocated array of variable length strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, memory-management

I have a dynamically allocated array of strings, I have made it so that the last item is always `NULL`. Now, I want to implement all kinds of sorting functions, beginning with alphabetical (but I'm not concerned about the comparison function itself here).

I have written this basic sorting function:

```
void string_sort(char **array)
{
    char *tmp = malloc(sizeof(char*));
    int i = 0;

    while (array[i + 1] != NULL) {

        int j = 0;

        while (array[j + 1] != NULL) {

            if (strcmp(array[j], array[j + 1]) > 0) {
                strcpy(tmp, array[j]);                    /* line 91 */
                strcpy(array[j], array[j + 1]);           /* line 92 */
                strcpy(array[j + 1], tmp);
            }
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    free(tmp);
}
```

Now, this function seems to work, the sorting is correct. But valgrind says these multiple times:

`Invalid write of size 1` (on line 92)

`Invalid read of size 1` (on lines 91 and 92)

What am I doing wrong to cause havoc in the memory?

Comment: You have an array of pointers. You can just swap them; no need to copy a string. As they have a variable length, this is a very bad idea anyway. What if you yopc one string to a shorter?

Comment: Also you allocate the wrong type. A pointer is not an array!

Comment: You do not need to write a full sort routine for each type of sort you want to accomplish, use `qsort` and you only need write a comparison function to have `qsort` handle the sorting for you. (and it will be 10 times faster than any sort routine you write)

Comment: If you are allocating for an array of pointers to type, you can individually allocate only the amount of memory each string requires. (it is called a *jagged* or *ragged* array). `qsort` works equally well with jagged arrrays.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes, using this for anything real would be unwise, I know a thing or two about sorting algorithms. This is merely for learning, I'm trying to learn more about things closer to the hardware. Thanks for the `qsort` tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In stead of *copying* the texts, which will invariably lead to memory errors unless all text buffers have the same lenght (not: the strings have the same length), you can simply *exchange* the pointers:

```
  if (strcmp(array[j], array[j + 1]) > 0) {
    char *tmp= array[j];              /* line 91 */
    array[j]= array[j + 1];           /* line 92 */
    array[j + 1]= tmp;
  }
```

Comment: And then I only need `char *tmp;` instead of a `malloc`. Thanks, I'm trying to expand from web dev to more low level stuff, so no real clue of memory management yet.

Comment: @Roope: Your `malloc` is wrong anyway. In fact, you now allocate a `char *`. Verify your conceptions about `malloc`, pointers and arrays.

Comment: I agree with Olaf, although you don't need malloc with this solution.

Comment: @Olaf Yes, I see now that it is quite wrong indeed. Anyway, verifying my conceptions is exactly what I am doing here. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Roope: But this is not the place to tutor you about C conceptions. stack overflow is a Q&A site. You will not get the whole picture required for non-trivial programs just by asikng about single issues. Do yourself a favour and read a C book, starting from the basics (if they are too basic, just advance faster).

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are allocating memory of size of your address length

```
char *tmp = malloc(sizeof(char*));
```

What will happen when you have a string larger then that? Surely out of bound read/write and UB. Thats what valgrind is warning about.

---

Allocate a large enough memory, to hold all the strings. If the largest a string in that example can be is 100 characters, then

```
char *tmp = malloc(100); //size of char is 1
```